# Can pepper emulator take audio for speech?

Tags: pepper

I don't have an actual robot right now. I would like to work on a project for educational purposes. I got the QiSDK tutorials running and have a Pepper emulator with Android Studio.

While testing I realized that I can't actually speak to the emulator. I can only simulate speech by actually typing it into the Dialogue window. Is this the limitation of the pepper emulator?

Can I really not test the speech recognition features of Pepper with the listen action?!?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a limitation of the speech recognition, which providers are licensed only on real robots. So yes, you cannot test speech recognition without a real robot, only dialogue management.